# Deleting wagtail.core from INSTALLED APPs throws error

Tags: wagtail

This week I've been in the process of incrementally upgrading a project written in Wagtail 2.15.3. I now have it running successfully in Wagtail 4.2.4.

Before upgrading to Wagtail 5.0, I checked to make sure that all references to wagtail.core were removed from my code, which they now are.

But when I remove wagtail.core from my INSTALLED APPS, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class wagtail.models.i18n.Locale doesn't declare an 
explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I've tried several things and searched widely for answers, but I'm stumped.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you remove it completely from INSTALLED_APPS, or replace it with an entry for `"wagtail"`? It should be the latter.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that seems to have fixed i! At least in Wagtail 4.1.6, which I had to roll back to last night because of another problem.